# SQL Server 2008 R2 Job fails but maintenance plan succeeds

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server Agent job running a maintenance plan. While the maintenance plan is working properly, the job reports failure with the following:

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  
Version 10.50.2500.0 for 64-bit  
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.  

Started: 5:30:00 PM    
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).   
Started: 5:30:00 PM  Finished: 5:34:57 PM  Elapsed:  297.479 seconds
```

I have tried:

- Setting the step to run in 32-bit mode (no change)
- `sp_configure 'allow updates',0`  (It returned that this was already the set value and nothing changed)
- Creating a new job and setting it run the maintenance plan (same results)

I just can't figure out why the job sees a failure when the maintenance plan is working and reporting success itself and it's driving me crazy.

Here's my exact SQL version if it helps/matters:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64)   Jun 11 2012 16:41:53    
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation    
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server will always (almost) tell you why a job failed. You may have to drill down in Job History to see the exact reason but its there somewhere.

Comment: I've tried going through the job history and logging the job step to a file and via this method:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1394/how-to-store-longer-sql-agent-job-step-output-messages/

I didn't get anything more helpful. If there's another way to log that you're aware of I'd be happy to try that too.